# How to concatenate a list of words into a sentence with "and" before last item in Excel? (Excel 2016)

Tags: concatenation

Mindful this was addressed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915165/how-to-concatenate-a-list-of-words-into-a-sentence-with-and-before-last-item-i), but I am not able to tweak the code to remove the comma before the "and" when a list has more than 2 items.

I like Ron's answer but I do not see how to modify his function to choose depending the UK or US rules.